# How to close a window/activity after a certain amount of time

Tags: android

am writing an android application, it allow someone add two numbers and input the answer. but I want this numbers to display for only 5 seconds and then a new number show up, if they input the correct or wrong answer, the timer reset and display new numbers..
i have written the code that does the random numbers and other just the timer am unable to do
someone help please

Comment: Take a look at the CountDownTimer class

Answer (score 1):

Using a Handler and Runnable should work for you but don't use an Anonymous runnable as they can cause memory leaks. Instead extend runnable into a static class and use `removeCallbacks` in `onDestroy`.

Also you can use WeakReference as `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called so a WeakReference will allow GC to free up the memory if your activity gets killed

```
public class BarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private FooRunnable mRunnable;

    private void finishActivityAfterDelay(int milliSeconds) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new FooRunnable(this);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000); // 5 seconds
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private static class FooRunnable implements Runnable {
        private WeakReference<AppCompatActivity> mWeakActivity;

        public FooRunnable(AppCompatActivity activity) {
            mWeakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AppCompatActivity activity = mWeakActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) activity.finish();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand it

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android.os.Handler` class to do so,
Like

`private Handler handler = new Handler(); // Create Handler`

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // Perform action here...
     }           
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3 * 1000); // action will be performed after 3 seconds.
```

Comment: m sorry but at least you have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000/*modify value as per need*/, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //millisUntilFinised is the remaining time
     }

     public void onFinish() {
        //timer finished .Do what you need to do next here
     }
  };
```

use `timer.start();`where you had to start the timer.

Comment: declare a global timer varaible as above and use timer.start() when you had to start the countdown

Comment: It didn't work as expected....if I place what I want it to do in the onthick, it repeat d code for 3sec,if I put it in the onfinish, it waits for 3seconds before showing my code....i want the timer to do a particular code after 3seconds and not wait for 3seconds to do the code...can you help me please

Comment: doesn't after 3 secs mean waiting for 3 secs? add timer.start() at the point where your code has to be shown after 3 secs.I think you are misplacing the timer.start()

Comment: No...I want it to write a message on a textfield and after 3seconds it replaces it with another text...but that's not what it's doing now...right now, it wait for 3seconds then it writes on the text screen and that's all

Comment: after setting the first text call timer.start() then Onfinish() set the second text